# C# Doesn't Remove Backslashes While Writing JSON Data Into File

Tags: c#, json, backslash

I am trying to add some data into a big json file so I'm trying to do it in C#, I have opened the file, wrote my data into it but while writing the final data into .Json file, the string that JsonConverter.SerializeObject returns has backslashes, the original string does not have it (it doesn't appear while looking thorough the `Text Visualizer` but the final data that is written into the .Json file still has the backslashes.

This is what it is when I'm looking at Text Visualizer;

```
{
  "GID_0": "TUR",
  "NAME_0": "Turkey",
  "GID_1": "TUR.1_1",
  "NAME_1": "Adana",
  "NL_NAME_1": "",
  "GID_2": "TUR.1.1_1",
  "NAME_2": "Aladağ",
  "VARNAME_2": "",
  "NL_NAME_2": "",
  "TYPE_2": "District",
  "ENGTYPE_2": "District",
  "CC_2": "",
  "HASC_2": "TR.AA.AL",
  "NUFUS": "16653"
}
```

But the real data in the file is this;

```
"{\r\n  \"GID_0\": \"TUR\",\r\n  \"NAME_0\": \"Turkey\",\r\n  \"GID_1\": \"TUR.1_1\",\r\n  \"NAME_1\": \"Adana\",\r\n  \"NL_NAME_1\": \"\",\r\n  \"GID_2\": \"TUR.1.10_1\",\r\n  \"NAME_2\": \"Aladağ\",\r\n  \"VARNAME_2\": \"\",\r\n  \"NL_NAME_2\": \"\",\r\n  \"TYPE_2\": \"District\",\r\n  \"ENGTYPE_2\": \"District\",\r\n  \"CC_2\": \"\",\r\n  \"HASC_2\": \"TR.AA.AS\",\r\n  \"NUFUS\": \"16653\"\r\n}"
```

This is how I try to do this in code;

```
 using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"D:\districts_of_turkey.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                JObject results = JObject.Parse(json);

                foreach(var result in results["features"])
                {
                    string type = (string)result["type"];
                    string geometryType = (string)result["geometry"]["type"];
                    JArray geometryStr = JArray.FromObject(result["geometry"]["coordinates"]);
                    string properties = result["properties"].ToString();
                    var propertiesArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertiesForJSON>(properties);

                    for (int j = 0; j < districts.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        string district = districts[j].Ilce.Split('-')[0].Split('(')[1].TrimEnd(')').ToUpper(turkey);
                        string province = districts[j].Ilce.Split('-')[0].Split('(')[0].ToUpper(turkey);
                        if ((province == propertiesArray.NAME_1.ToUpper(turkey) || province == propertiesArray.NAME_1) && (district == propertiesArray.NAME_2.ToUpper(turkey) || district == propertiesArray.NAME_2))
                        {
                            propertiesArray.NUFUS = districts[j].Nufus;
                            lst.Add(propertiesArray);
                            break;
                        }else if(j == districts.Count - 2)
                        {
                            exceptions.Add("İL = " + propertiesArray.NAME_1 + " // İLÇE = " + propertiesArray.NAME_2);
                        }
                    }
                    /*
                     {"GID_0":"TUR","NAME_0":"Turkey","GID_1":"TUR.32_1","NAME_1":"Eskişehir","NL_NAME_1":"","GID_2":"TUR.32.10_1","NAME_2":"Mihalıççık","VARNAME_2":"","NL_NAME_2":"","TYPE_2":"District","ENGTYPE_2":"District","CC_2":"","HASC_2":"TR.ES.MK"}
                     */
                    string propertyStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertiesArray);
                    propertyStr = removeBackSlash(JToken.Parse(propertyStr).ToString());

                    string propertyStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertiesArray);
                    result["properties"] = propertyStr;
                }

                File.WriteAllText(@"D:\districts_with_populationtwo.json", results.ToString());
            }
```

```
public class PropertiesForJSON
{
    public string GID_0;
    public string NAME_0;
    public string GID_1;
    public string NAME_1;
    public string NL_NAME_1;
    public string GID_2;
    public string NAME_2;
    public string VARNAME_2;
    public string NL_NAME_2;
    public string TYPE_2;
    public string ENGTYPE_2;
    public string CC_2;
    public string HASC_2;
    public string NUFUS;
}
```

Also this is how I write the final data into the file (The code above is one result);

```
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\districts_with_population.json", results.ToString());
```

**How can I actually write the string into the file with JSON format?**

Comment: You might want to show us how you generate the JSON (with code) and the full process through to writing it to a file. It doesn't have to be your actual code, but it should be a [mcve].

Comment: You double-encoded. That is a JSON representation of a JSON representation of an object.

Comment: So your data has the actually has the characters `\r\n` ?

Comment: @Amadan That seems like a good possibility, if only OP would show us the relevant code...

Comment: Edited. All the code is above, since it is not  important code I just copy-pasted the whole.

Comment: @TheGeneral, my original data is minified so no it doesn't have `\r\n` in it but the data that program writes into .json file does have those.

Comment: `string propertyStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertiesArray);` serializes `propertiesArray` to JSON. `result["properties"] = propertyStr;` adds it to the `result` JSON object as a _string value_. `results.ToString()` serializes the object, and naturally treats the `propertyStr` value as a string, so it escapes the values. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: You're not wrong but the issue is that "propertyStr" has backslashes while replacing the value on `result["properties"]`. `result["properties"]` normally has`                     {"GID_0":"TUR","NAME_0":"Turkey","GID_1":"TUR.32_1","NAME_1":"Eskişehir","NL_NAME_1":"","GID_2":"TUR.32.10_1","NAME_2":"Mihalıççık","VARNAME_2":"","NL_NAME_2":"","TYPE_2":"District","ENGTYPE_2":"District","CC_2":"","HASC_2":"TR.ES.MK"}` type of string.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean the issue is actually at the `propertyStr` level? If you just write `propertyStr` to a file, how does it look?

Comment: The issue is about the serializing. VS still sees the string with backslashes and it writes the string that has backlashes into the file. When I try to write the string on the console, it looks fine without any unnecessary chars but when I say File.WriteAllText, it just writes with the backslashes.

Comment: @I.Atabay: No, `File.WriteAllText` doesn't add anything. I suspect there's something odd about the way you're writing the string to the console vs how you're writing it to the file, but it's really not `File.WriteAllText` that's at fault here. (And VS isn't writing the file at all.) I've proposed a solution in the answer, but if that's not what you're looking for, please rewrite the question to include a [mcve] - making sure that you tell us what you expect as well as what happens.

Comment: @JonSkeet just submitted his answer and it works fine. Turns out Serializing is not a good idea if you need it as a string.

Comment: @I.Atabay: No, that's the wrong less. Serializing *is* what you want to do in order to get a JSON string representation of an object. But you were serializing to a string, then using that string in a bigger JSON model, then serializing that bigger JSON model - and that's *not* a good idea. In most cases, you only want serialization to happen once, rather than in a nested way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "wrong lesson".

Comment: Oh I see now. Double serializing was the problem. Now ran the program with only one serialization on the string and works just fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been noted in comments, the problem is that you're converting an object into a JSON string here:

```
string propertyStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertiesArray);
```

And then you're setting that string (which includes double quotes etc) as a JSON property here:

```
result["properties"] = propertyStr;
```

I believe you don't want it *as a string property*, but just as the object. So instead, you want the value of the property to be the `JToken` itself. So I'd expect this to work:

```
result["properties"] = JToken.FromObject(propertiesArray);
```

Comment: I thought it'd to the job but as it looks, it doesn't. Thank you for your time and effort Jon :).

Comment: @I.Atabay: Can I check that you understand *why* it didn't work before? That's as important as getting the answer. In the JSON model itself, you want the value of the `properties` property to be an object - but before, the value was a string, that happened to have JSON content. If you think carefully about the data model, it can avoid this sort of problem.

Comment: Since it shows `result["properties"]` in the string form, I didn't think it was an object. And that occupied my last few hours. And now I do know that even though it is shown as string, it is still an object. Data is something I collected from the internet, I just needed to add more values into it. And since doing it manually would take probably a day, a few hours did seem better :)